# How to join 3 tables into one table with JPA?

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am creating an API where I have 3 tables called User, Book and Status. And I want to create a combined table User_Book_Status. I am not sure how to implement this in JPA. I think all tables have M:N relationship with each other. How should I join these 3 tables?

Here is my design for the database.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKhg4.png]

`User.java`

```java
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String username;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    public User() {}
    //Getters and setters omitted.
}
```

`Book.java`

```java
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String title;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String author;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int pages;

    public Book() {}
    //Getters and setters omitted.
}
```

`Status.java`

```
import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity
public class Status {
    public enum ReadingStatus {READING,
                               FINISHED,
                               ONHOLD}
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ReadingStatus status;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Eren, just added an example of implementing your model as an Entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an example of how to implement your solution already working:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_book_status")
public class UserBookStatus {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
  private User user;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "book_id")
  private Book book;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "status_id")
  private Status status;
}
```

@Table to specify the name of the Table, so you can change the name of the entity freely.

@ManyToOne means that you can have many records of UserBookStatus for a single user, or book or status.

@JoinColumn use to specify the name of the column in your entity that maps to the @Id from the entity (User,Book,Status) you are referencing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you don't really need an entity for `Status`. I would model it like this:

```
@Entity
public class Loan {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Book book;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ReadingStatus status;

    //...
 }
```

Also, you could make the relationships bidirectional, so that both `User` and `Book`has a list of `Loan`s.

Comment: Your mappings are all wrong. OneToMany normally is for Collections, and you are using Enumerated instead of the ID for the relationship

Comment: Ah, thanks. The enumeration was added as a member of the entity on purpose, as there is no need to create an entity just to hold an enumerated type.